# Add AMP collapse submenu support flag to AMP on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, mobile, submenu

as the title says - In order to allow sub-menus to collapse on the AMP-Versions of my page I would like to add the code provided by AMP-Project to my Wordpress website.
It can be found here:
https://amp-wp.org/documentation/playbooks/navigation-sub-menu-buttons/

My problem is that I have no idea where that code needs to be added to my Wordpress page.
Adding it to the Head-Section did not help yet.
Also I assume that I have to replace placeholders within the code but I don't know which.

My website can be found here https://picjoy.de

Answer (score 1):

Nice website! For submenu's you can modify your existing theme's navigation menu, or use the functions.php file as an alternative. I'm a contributor to the plugin so I'd also be happy to help if you want to post a support topic with the plugin in the support forums